# Repeat one SEQUENCE value if another CELL is not empty - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, count, sequence, flatten

I've been trying to figure this out, but I had no success until now.

I found how to repeat a specific sequence (forever), how to show a sequence (1 to N) value only if another cell is not empty. But I can't find a solution to repeat a specific sequence (1 to 11 as many time as necessary) value only if a cell is NOT empty.

The table will be updated by a Google Form, the empty cell to check would be the timestamp.

[image: Here is a image showing the idea]

[Here is a link to a working sheet, with the idea hard-coded](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YoFXDIzipzyAlUiFvtYaMGJakFD6J5HDoOTLd4jhmXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/11); 11; 
 LAMBDA(x; y; y))); COUNTA(A2:A); 1)
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/11); 11)-(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/11); 1; 0)*11)); COUNTA(A2:A); 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, guys! I added all three answer to that Google Sheet, so anyone looking for a similar can bennefit from your ideas. I locked the sheet for view only. I went with:

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/11); 11; 
 LAMBDA(x; y; y))); COUNTA(A2:A); 1)

I'll look into it, to understand better how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your could try the following in C2:

```
=scan(0,A2:A,lambda(a,r,if(len(r),if(a=11,1,a+1),)))
```

SCAN down the range A2:A, adding 1 to the accumulator each time a nonempty cell is found, until the accumulator has reached 11 at which point it reverts to 1 for the next filled cell. Return nothing for empty cells.